# Which sourdough starter should i keep?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I decided to make 2 sourdough starters, to see if one would come out better. I only want to keep one and I dont know which one to choose. One has formed a hooch, while the other has not but otherwise they are identical in size, consistency, and smell. Which one should I keep?

Comment: If you have used identical amounts and ratios, the one with the hooch _may_ be the one with the faster metabolism. (Hooch -> hungry starter) Whether this translates in any way to different baking properties, I honestly can’t say.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to decide which starter works best for you and which one you like more is to bake a bread with each of them.

I would suggest to make them at the same time (or one after the other if you don't have the oven capacity), so you can have a direct taste comparison. Don't worry about having too much bread, you can freeze part of each loaf if you don't think you can eat it all while still fresh.